# Can not install pyaudio library in python

Tags: python, pyaudio

As I am running CMD as administrator and trying to install pyaudio by `pip install pyaudio` I am getting the folloing error. I also have installed *MS-VS C++ 14*.

> Installing collected packages: pyaudio
>       Running setup.py install for pyaudio ... error
>       ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
>        command: 'c:\users\cloud analogy\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\python.exe' -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\Users\CLOUDA~1\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-dcxzpwri\pyaudio\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\Users\CLOUDA~1\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-dcxzpwri\pyaudio\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record 'C:\Users\CLOUDA~1\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-1s6dsj4b\install-record.txt' --single-version-externally-managed --compile
>            cwd: C:\Users\CLOUDA~1\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-dcxzpwri\pyaudio\
>       Complete output (9 lines):
>       running install
>       running build
>       running build_py
>       creating build
>       creating build\lib.win32-3.7
>       copying src\pyaudio.py -> build\lib.win32-3.7
>       running build_ext
>       building '_portaudio' extension
>       error: Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 is required. Get it with "Microsoft Visual C++ Build Tools": https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/downloads/
>       ----------------------------------------
>   ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: 'c:\users\cloud analogy\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\python.exe' -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\Users\CLOUDA~1\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-dcxzpwri\pyaudio\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\Users\CLOUDA~1\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-dcxzpwri\pyaudio\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record 'C:\Users\CLOUDA~1\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-1s6dsj4b\install-record.txt' --single-version-externally-managed --compile Check the logs for full command output.

Comment: The proposed solution is hidden in the middle of the error message: Go to [https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/downloads/](https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/downloads/), download and install "Microsoft Visual C++ Build Tools".

Comment: i have already installed the MSVC++14

Comment: Does this answer your question? [PyAudio error at the time of intallation (subprocess-exited-with-error)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71072094/pyaudio-error-at-the-time-of-intallation-subprocess-exited-with-error)

Answer (score 1):

Since you are on windows, go to [https://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#pyaudio](https://www.lfd.uci.edu/%7Egohlke/pythonlibs/#pyaudio)
and download pyaudio according to the version of python that you have
Then navigate to the directory that contains your file and install the module except replacing the module name with the file name

e.g.

> pip install PyAudio‑0.2.11‑cp39‑cp39‑win_amd64.whl