# pyaudio - legacy-install-failure

Tags: python, pyaudio

```
Installing collected packages: pyaudio
  Running setup.py install for pyaudio ... error
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error
  
  × Running setup.py install for pyaudio did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [16 lines of output]
      running install
      running build
      running build_py
      creating build
      creating build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-3.10
      copying src/pyaudio.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-3.10
      running build_ext
      building '_portaudio' extension
      creating build/temp.macosx-10.9-universal2-3.10
      creating build/temp.macosx-10.9-universal2-3.10/src
      clang -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -Wunreachable-code -fno-common -dynamic -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -arch arm64 -arch x86_64 -g -DMACOSX=1 -I/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/include/python3.10 -c src/_portaudiomodule.c -o build/temp.macosx-10.9-universal2-3.10/src/_portaudiomodule.o
      src/_portaudiomodule.c:29:10: fatal error: 'portaudio.h' file not found
      #include "portaudio.h"
               ^~~~~~~~~~~~~
      1 error generated.
      error: command '/usr/bin/clang' failed with exit code 1
      [end of output]
  
  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
error: legacy-install-failure

× Encountered error while trying to install package.
╰─> pyaudio

note: This is an issue with the package mentioned above, not pip.
hint: See above for output from the failure.
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to fix installation issues for PyAudio, PortAudio: "fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'portaudio.h': No such file or directory"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51992375/how-to-fix-installation-issues-for-pyaudio-portaudio-fatal-error-c1083-canno)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [PyAudio error at the time of intallation (subprocess-exited-with-error)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71072094/pyaudio-error-at-the-time-of-intallation-subprocess-exited-with-error)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Hey this question was already asked : [PyAudio error at the time of intallation (subprocess-exited-with-error)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71072094/pyaudio-error-at-the-time-of-intallation-subprocess-exited-with-error)

You need to download the wheel (.whl) file on the website quoted in the answer ([https://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#pyaudio](https://www.lfd.uci.edu/%7Egohlke/pythonlibs/#pyaudio)).
And then, you install it using `pip install filename.whl` using the cmd in the directory where you downloaded the file in .whl .